# How do we use the functions of an object which is generic

Tags: java, generic-programming

Implementing a class HashTable1 whose functions take generic parameter key of type K. In real key is an object of class Pair. So how do I access the instance variables (fname and lname) of key in class HasTable1 ?

```
class HashTable1<K,T> implements MyHashTable_<K,T>{
   BST[] bt;
   int hashtablesize;

    HashTable1(int n){
       bt = new BST[n];
       this.hashtablesize=n;
     }

     public int insert(K key,T obj){
         String str = key.toString();
         long index = Hashfunctions.djb2(str,this.hashtablesize);
         return bt[(int)index].insert(key.getf(),obj); //error at              key.getf()
     }

    class Pair {
      String fname;
      String lname;

    Pair(String fname,String lname){
       this.fname=fname;
       this.lname=lname;
    }

    public String getf (){
       return this.fname;
    }
    public String getl(){
       return this.lname;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format(this.fname+this.lname);
}

}
```

Comment: With your current code, `key` has to be of type `Pair` if you want  to use `key.getf`. You should rethink whether you need the `Pair` class at all.

Comment: But I have to implement it by using generic typing and it's compulsory to use the Pair class

Comment: Is this an exercise in understanding Java Generics, or do you really need a `Map` data structure whose key class is `Pair` ?

Comment: If the class is specifically intended for use with `Pair` keys, then it's not generic. At least, it's not generic on the *key* side. However, it makes no sense to have method to access a key on the hashtable level, since a hashtable will contain many keys.

Comment: shouldn't the classes `HashTable1` and `Pair` be `public` and their attributes `private`?

Comment: Please consider adding your assignment definition to your question. There may be things you don't interpret correctly in it.

Comment: When you create an instance of class `HashTable1`, you need to supply the actual types, for example: `HashTable1<Pair, Object> ht1 = new HashTable1<>()`

Comment: As a part of assignment I need to implement in this way only

Comment: Are you allowed to use your own definition of `Pair`?

Comment: I think you must use java reflection API to reflect(~="scan") your code on runtime. Here is an example where I learnt about it: https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation

Comment: Alternatively you can define an interface that declares the methods/variables you need, and instead of T you use this interface.